# .NET and Closing SQL Server connections

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am having a hard time figuring out why the following constructor will not close connnections.  When I view the active connections.  Here is the code that I have.

```
Public Sub New(ByVal UserID As Integer)

Dim oConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connStr").ToString())
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("stored proc", oConn)
Dim sdr As SqlDataReader

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", UserID)
oConn.Open()
sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Try
    If Not sdr.HasRows Then
        sdr.Close()

        If Not oConn Is Nothing Then
            If oConn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
                oConn.Close()
            End If
        End If
        cmd.Dispose()

        Exit Sub
    End If
    'User has account in WATS, proceed to load account information
    While sdr.Read
         _firstname = Convert.ToString(sdr("First Name"))
        _lastname = Convert.ToString(sdr("Last Name"))
    End While

Catch ex As Exception
    'Throw New Exception("User Error: " + ex.Message)
Finally
    sdr.Close()

    If Not oConn Is Nothing Then
        If oConn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            oConn.Close()
        End If
    End If
    cmd.Dispose()
End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks OK at first glance; how are you determining that it's not closing connections?  Do you keep seeing new connections opening up in SQL Server every time you run this, or are you just seeing the one connection?

Comment: First, you're best off taking advantage of the `Using` statement as John suggests below. Secondly, because of the way you've organized the code, there are windows in which you've allocated & opened the connection, but that an exception can occur in which you do not clean up the connection. For instance, what if `sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()` throws?

Answer (score 2):

Probably open due to connection pooling.

[ADO.NET Connection Pooling & SQLServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228/ado-net-connection-pooling-sqlserver)

Comment: It turns out it is connection pooling.  All of the connections are in a sleep state.  I need to take a look as to why this sproc is being called so many times.  But I thought that if I am passing the same parameters to the db then it would use the pooled connection.  Is there something I am misunderstanding or doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same connection string?

Comment: Yes, all calls are to the same db using the same connection.

Comment: The error I am getting is "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

So it seems that the problem may not be that I am forgetting to close connections but that I am opening too many.  Does that sound right?

Comment: No that does not sound right. Could you remove the exception comment. See if there are any exceptions.

Comment: I have removed it. The problem is that there are too many connections going on. I am actually going through all calls to make sure an exception is handled correctly. I also increased the max pool size and it seems to be working fine

Answer (score 2):

You need to be implementing `Using` blocks. Partial fix:

```
Using oConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connStr").ToString()) 
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("stored proc", oConn) 

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", UserID) 
        oConn.Open() 
        Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader() 
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I would question the word "need" because this is one alternative to a route already being partially taken in the question with Try Finally.

Comment: @jdk: the answer is that it's much easier to get `Using` blocks right than try/finally.

Comment: S. I agree with Using being easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim oConn As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim sdr As SqlDataReader

Try
    oConn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connStr").ToString())
    cmd = New SqlCommand("stored proc", oConn)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", UserID)
    oConn.Open()
    sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Catch ex As Exception

Finally

    If Not IsNothing(sdr) Then
        If Not sdr.IsClosed Then sdr.Close()
    End If

    If Not IsNothing(oConn) Then
        If oConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then oConn.Close()
    End If

End Try
```