# What are best practices on managing database connections in .NET?

Tags: .net, database-connection, connection-pooling

Regarding best practice for managing database connections in a .NET application -- I know that, in general, it's bad to pass around a connection object.

However, I have some specific curiosities:

---

**1. I have two instances of business
    objects, of different classes, in a
    parent-child relationship (the child
    is private.) Which of the following
    is best?**

- Keep one private static connection open and shared, used by both objects, and left open until the parent is disposed.
- Keep two private static connections open, one for each object, not to be
  closed until the object is disposed.
- Do not keep static connections; open and subsequently close a new
  connection for every method that requires it. However, most of my methods only run 1-3 queries, so this seems inefficient... ?

---

**2. My second question is essentially the same, but for a single form. What's best here?**

- Keep one private static connection open and shared for the lifetime of the form.
- Do not keep a static connection; open and subsequently close a connection for every method in the form that requires it (again, a mere 1-3 queries per method.)

Comment: Is this a winform or ASP.Net application?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection-pooling

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connection Pooling in .NET/SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223/connection-pooling-in-net-sql-server)

Comment: It's a WinForm app. Also, considering the specific nature of my questions, I wouldn't consider this a duplicate -- my question isn't about writing my own connection pool, but how to optimize my code in correlation with the existing .NET connection pool.

Comment: The theory is you should not be accessing the database from your business logic - it should be in a separate data-access class. (Say for example in the future you need to store them offline in XML, or use Oracle rather than SQL Server... you don't want to re-write your business logic!). Going to make an answer now..

Comment: @Rob: I think you should read the question I felt was a duplicate. The question is different, but the answers there actually answer your question. If you don't think that answers it, I bet one of the other 239 questions with the same tag would answer it.

Comment: Can't believe how many people are suggesting keeping a connection object around and alive.. it's just not right!

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone: Agreed.

@Rob: I think you really should be considering why your business objects know anything whatsoever about a database connection.

Comment: Kieren, John; thanks for your input. It's helped a lot (and you were right about the answers in the other thread.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(Was a comment)...

The theory is you should not be accessing the database from your business logic - it should be in a separate data-access class. (Say for example in the future you need to store them offline in XML, or use Oracle rather than SQL Server... you don't want to re-write your business logic!)

Your business objects should not have database connections associated with them.  The connection should be opened in some DAL factory-type method, the object retrieved/built, then the connection closed and the object returned.

The business objects themselves should contain business logic fields and methods, which might call back to the Data Access Layer, which should create a new database connection for each DAL method.

Your inefficiency fears can be put to rest by using Connection Pooling, which means that if you open and close a connection hundreds of times, chances are they will all use the same one.  But you should not be keeping database connections hanging around at all - especially not as members on a class.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 9):

My understanding is that connections should only stay open as long as needed.  Most of the time I've seen connections in Using statements, similar to

```
using (DBConnection db = new DBConnection(connectString))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This was my understanding as well. However, I'm concerned about the overhead of constantly opening / closing connections when half of my methods do very minimal work, and I wonder if keeping a single connection for a form would be more efficient.

Comment: @Rob: the point of a connection pool is that the real connection won't keep getting opened and closed. "Open" will simply get an existing, open connection from the pool.

Answer (score 8):

This link may be helpful: [Best Practices for Using ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx)

Here's an interesting excerpt.

> For best performance, keep connections
>   to the database open only when
>   required. Also, reduce the number of
>   times you open and close a connection
>   for multiple operations.

I've always followed the practice of opening connections in a using block, so that the Dispose method (and hence the Close method) is always called without my worrying about it. Using this approach I've never encountered a situation where poor performance was linked either to excessive concurrent connections or excessive setup or tear down operations.

Answer (score 6):

In answer to both questions, if you are using something that has connection pooling, like ADO.NET, you should code your queries to keep the connection open as *short as possible*. I.e. `open and subsequently close a new connection for every method that requires it.`. When you close the connection it will be returned to the connection pool and reused on a subsequent query and thus you will not incur a performance penalty by opening and closing a bunch of connections. The advantage is that you won't risk leaking connections that you forgot to close and in the long run, you'll have fewer simultaneous connections open than if you keep connections open for long periods of time. It doesn't matter whether the application is a Windows form instead of a Web form: keep connections open as short as possible.