# What is the best practice to connect/disconnect to a database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

I'd like to know how to work with connectivity to a database in MEAN stack application. In particular, when should I create a connection to a database and when should I destroy a connection to a database. Should I create and destroy a connection on every new HTTP request or should I store a once created connection and use it for any subsequent requests as long as possible. I use Mongoose as a modeling tool.

Here is an example. 
This is my `routes.js` file with a route `/index`. A request to this route should fetch some date from MongoDb database. It bothers me how I connect and disconnect to a database now. Yes, I connect and disconnect to a database exactly as written in Mongoose docs, but it it the right way to do it in a serious production environment?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var config = require('./db-config');

// I create a Mongoose instance as a module object,
// as opposite to create it in every request handler function below.
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var productSchema = require('../db/productSchema'); // model schema is also a module-wide object

// And here is a request handler function.
// It is called on every request as a brand new.
// I create and destroy a database connection inside this request handler
router.get('/index', function(req, res, next) {

    // I connect to a database on every request.
    // Do I need to do it here in a request handler?
    // May I do it outside of this request handler on a module-wide level?
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://my_database');

    // I create a new connection here in a request handler.
    // So it lives only during this request handler run.
    // Is this the right way? May I do it outside of this request handler 
    // on a module-wide level and somehow keep this connection and use it 
    // in every subsequent requests to this or any other route in the app?
    var db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('connecting', function() {
        console.log('connecting');
    });

    db.on('connected', function() {
        console.log('connected');
    });

    db.on('open', function() {
        console.log('open');
    });

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));

    db.once('open', function(cb) {
        var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
        Product.find({category: "books"}, function(err, prods) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);

            // I close a connection here in a callback. 
            // As soon as successfully fetched the data. 
            // Do I need to close it after every request? 
            // What is the right place and time to do it? 
            db.close(disconnect);
            res.json(prods);
        });
    });
})
```

Found some good answers:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query

[What are best practices on managing database connections in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258788/what-are-best-practices-on-managing-database-connections-in-net)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Its best practice to have your db connection in a separate module (db.js)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbname', function(){
    console.log('mongodb connected')
})
module.exports = mongoose
```

Each model should have a separate module that takes in the db connection (post.js)

```
var db = require('../db.js')
var Post = db.model('Post', {
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    body: {type: String, required: true},
    date: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }  
})

module.exports = Post
```

Then whenever you need to use that data set just require it and make calls

```
var Post = require('/models/post')
Post.save()
Post.find()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an opinion based question I'd say. What I use for my app is

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile('index.html');
});
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/my_db');
```

This way I create a connection once rather than on every HTTP request. Your way should work fine but it seems you will have to connect and disconnect the db to your app way too many times specially when the app is in development.

Answer (score 2):

You want your connection to act like a singleton so as mentioned in the answer above it makes sense to do it outside of, and preferable before your routes:

```
var compression = require('compression');
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');
...

app.use(compression());
// db
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database
```

config/database.js:

```
module.exports = {
'url' : '@localhost:27017/dbname'
};
```

Comment: `mongoose.connect` is async. How do you make sure that the database connection is ready before routes?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution :

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { name } from '../package.json';
import * as localconfig from './local-config';
import debug from 'debug';
debug(name);
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const mongoUrl = localconfig.credentials.MONGO_URL;

import usersRoutes from './routes/users/user-routes';

app.use('/v1/users', usersRoutes);

mongoose.connect(mongoUrl)
    .then(() => {
        debug('DB connection successful');
        app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
            debug(`Running on port ${port}`);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        debug(err);
    });
```

You should first check weather the connection is successful or not and only then listen to a certain port. This is my `app.js` file where all the routes are loaded, so you do not have to call the db connection in all your files. You have a single config file where all the config is done. Your router file `user-routes.js` will look something similar to this:

```
import express from 'express';

import User from '../models/user'
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    User.find()
        .then((response) => res.json(response))
        .catch((err) => next(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: This question is mainly guidance, so try to add some reasoning why your solution is better than the one they already have