# Should I close a Mongoose connection after every model save?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose to manage my DB schemas. I save my models in a few places in my app. I'm wondering though if I should manually close and reopen the connection before and after each query respectively? I'm not sure of the performance implications.

For example in this `createUser()`, the db gets connected to, saves the model, and then closes the connection. This will happen every time the `createUser()` is called.

```js
function createUser() {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_PATH, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    const db = mongoose.connection
    db.once("open", function () {
        const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            name: String,
        })
        const UserModel = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
        const user = new UserModel({
            name: "John",
        })
        user.save().then(() => {
            mongoose.connection.close()
        })
    })
}
```

Or is it a better idea to just keep the connection alive in the entry point of the app and close it if the app terminates?

```js
// server.js

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_PATH, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
})

// ...

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    mongoose.connection.close(() => {
          process.exit(0);
      });
});
```

I'd also be curious to know, would the strategy change if using another DB driver, let's say MySQL?

Comment: keep connection alive if you need that every where in your project !

Comment: make your connection module and connect to it in entry point of your project

Comment: Thanks @mohsen - Is it because connecting and disconnecting multiple times is too expensive of an operation? Also is there any performance concern keeping the connection alive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this book [Mongoose For Application Development](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781782168195/2/ch02lvl1sec15/closing-the-connection)

> the general best practice is to open your connection at application start up, and keep it open. However, there are times when you will want to close the connection. For example, if your application is shutting down, or restarting, the database connection needs to be manually closed, or if you are running a single-hit script rather than a persistent application.

It's good to read **Options** part in [mongoosejs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html) document about some options that you can set in your connection string.

And check [best practice to connect to db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558140/what-is-the-best-practice-to-connect-disconnect-to-a-database) too.

According to mongoose documents:

> autoReconnect - The underlying MongoDB driver will automatically try to reconnect when it loses connection to MongoDB. Unless you are an extremely advanced user that wants to manage their own connection pool

As far as i know this kind of issue depends on your project scale.

After reading all reference you will come up with goods for your project.

Comment: thank you for this answer , that's so interesting !