# How to insert data quickly into SQL Server using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have an application in C# which receives data from different clients and insert that data into SQL Server. I get the data every second, or even faster, but I am facing some problem with my code:

```
static SqlConnection objSqlConn = null;
static SqlCommand objSqlCmd = null;

public static void SaveClientHistory(String strMessage, String strClientIP)
{
    try
    {
        using (objSqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
        {
                using (objSqlCmd = new SqlCommand("procInsertHistory", objSqlConn))
                {
                    objSqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    objSqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    objSqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strMessage", strMessage);
                    objSqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strClientIP", strClientIP);

                    objSqlConn.Open();
                    objSqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        throw Ex;
    }
    finally
    { 
        if(objSqlConn != null && objSqlConn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            objSqlConn.Close();
            objSqlConn.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Different types of exceptions occurred:

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.
>
> Internal connection fatal error.
>
> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting.

Please, advise me if there is any error in above code or suggest any other way to accomplish this task.

Thanks

Comment: Please check if you did not miss some details in your post like "my application handles multiple requests in parallel" or "I have no idea what `static` means and need an explanation" - it will make it easier to diagnose problem and offer fixes.

Comment: Side note: could you please also comment on why code needs to close connection 3 times (`using`, `.Close` and `.Dispose` calls in `finally` block).

Comment: Fast as in how Fast?

Comment: I suggest you to use an ORM,such as MicrosoftEntityFrameWork OR Telerik OpenAcess

Comment: @Kyle... Fast means almost 200 clients sending data with time interval of seconds and application should be capable to receive and store data in SQL.

Comment: Please Help.... Any Update?

Answer (score 2):

**Edited** - simplified the procedure further to better troubleshoot the issue: removed the try/catch because it wasn't doing anything helpful; method is no longer `static`; all inputs are now passed in as parameters - including `strConnectionString`; the connection timeout is explicitly set; the connection is opened before the `SqlCommand` object is instantiated; the command timeout is now 10 seconds.

As performance is a concern of yours, note that you should not be worried about trying to keep a connection open for re-use. By default, SQL Server connection pooling is turned on, so [there is no need to attempt to cache connections with your own methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8232/772086).

There seems like there is something going on besides attempting to open a connection and executing a non-query, so I tried to simplify your code a little further. I hope it helps with troubleshooting your issue.

```
public int SaveClientHistory(String strConnectionString, String strMessage, String strClientIP)
{
    // You can double-up using statements like this (for slightly better readability)
    using (SqlConnection objSqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
    {
        objSqlConn.ConnectionTimeout = 10; // Creating a connection times out after ten seconds 
        objSqlConn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand objSqlCmd = new SqlCommand("procInsertHistory", objSqlConn))
        {
            objSqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 10; // Creating a command times out after ten seconds
            objSqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            objSqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strMessage", strMessage);
            objSqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strClientIP", strClientIP);                 
            return objSqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, when without finally block face the following exception "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting."

Comment: @Muhammad I rewrote my answer, which was originally a list of suggested changes, to become a code sample. I hope that helps!

Comment: I have change the code as you mentioned above but still facing the problem "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting."...

Comment: Where is `strConnectionString` coming from? Does it have something like `connect timeout=0` in it? Otherwise, I am not sure why your connection appears to be stuck in the connecting state, but not timing out.

Comment: strConnectionString is just simple veriable which declare on class level and set from App.Config in class constructor like       String strConndbRSuiteLive = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all three errors are related with connection. In one of my applications, I implement you function like bellow. I hope this help you:

```
public static void SaveClientHistory(String strMessage, String strClientIP)
{
    SqlConnection objSqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    SqlCommand objSqlCmd = new SqlCommand("procInsertHistory", objSqlConn)
    objSqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    objSqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strMessage", strMessage);
    objSqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strClientIP", strClientIP);
    try{
        objSqlConn.Open();
        objSqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();               
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        throw Ex;
    }
    finally
    { 
        if(objSqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            objSqlConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have change the code as you mentioned above but still facing the problem "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting."...

Comment: It seems that your connection is somehow alive. Try to close your connection before opening it (It is dirty but maybe worked).

Comment: suggest me, If I make just one connection and remains it open and just execute command every time, will it work smoothly?